# dicscord.py rewrite not letting me send images

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

ok, so, first of all here is my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GXTp_hwFv48j1YOI-jOVU8JXmh0cklT3/view?usp=sharing
and it always says "discord" is not defined. but it is. because i have other commands that work.

Comment: Can you show a full traceback?

Comment: Hey HunterTheSoundGuy, linking to external website for code is not how you are supposed to ask question. Please edit your question and include the code snippet here, so people trying to help you have less hassle.

Comment: also if it says discord is not defined, you probably need to import discord first. You have only imported `discord.ext.command`and it does not contain command `discord.File`. I believe this can be fixed by adding `import discord` at the beginning, if it can not import it, you might need to install discord first by `pip install discord.py`